# pysnmp on demand trap receiver

Tags: python, multithreading, pysnmp

Is it possible (and how) to implement the following scenario using pysnmp:

1. start listening to traps (with some predefined timeout)
2. run some code
3. stop listening to traps and display the traps collected so far.

```
snmp_agent.receive_traps()
.... some code...
print(snmp_agent.get_traps())
```

from my understanding the trap listener must be run from a separate thread, otherwise it will block the code in step 2.
For reference here's the snmp agent method I'm using right now to receive traps.

```
def receive_traps(self, trap_event_timeout=40):

    trap_event_start = time()
    traps = []

    def event_timer(time_now):
        if time_now - trap_event_start > trap_event_timeout:
            self._snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.jobFinished(1)

    def cbFun(
        snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName, varBinds, cbCtx
    ):
        try:
            varBinds = [
                ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(name), value).resolveWithMib(
                    self._mib_view_controller
                )
                for name, value in varBinds
            ]
        except error.SmiError as err:
            print("MIB resolution error\n{}".format(err))
        else:
            traps.append(
                {
                    name.getMibSymbol()[1]: value.prettyPrint()
                    for name, value in varBinds
                }
            )

    trap_receiver = ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(self._snmp_engine, cbFun)
    self._snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.registerTimerCbFun(event_timer)
    self._snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

    try:
        self._snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
    except Exception:
        self._snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
        raise
    finally:
        self._snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.unregisterTimerCbFun(event_timer)
        trap_receiver.close(self._snmp_engine)
    return traps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer a couple of approaches for your consideration:

- Push the code implementing step (2) to a function and have pysnmp's main loop calling that function [periodically](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/carrier/base.py#L106). You trap processing code can block for a long time, may be have the processing code running in a thread.
- Implement your own main loop along the lines of [pysnmp's](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dispatch.py#L43) from where you can do step (2). May be in a thread as well.
- Have your trap processing code running in a thread (or in a subprocess) at all times reading incoming traps from the SNMP thread via `threading.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Queue`.

If trap processing can take time, my gut feeling would lean me towards the latter  approach (`multiprocessing` is awesome).